# How to make my function not pass the second parameter until later?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a small script with a voice recognition software.

I have set it up so that when the voice command recognizes a command, it fires up a function.

The function takes two parameters, state and tag.

For example, you can say

"{state} door {tag}.

Example: "{Open} door {a}"

state and tag can be anything. My function goes through it checking if it is a string, if it is a singular letter, if it matches with the database etc, and in the end sends the data to a form if everything passes. Point being, the first "barrier" these parameters have to pass through is:

```
if (typeof tag === "string" && tag.length === 1){ 

do stuff 

} else {
console.log(`Parameter ${tag} is either not a word, or not a singular 
letter.`);
}
```

It works perfectly with only one parameter/argument, aka tag, but with two, it passes "state" through as well??? Aka, my else console log is fired, saying things like "Open is either not a word..." etc.

Later in my code, state becomes relevant where it checks for example,

```
 if (state === open || state === closed) {}
```

My point being, how do I make it ignore that parameter until later when it is needed? Is there a way to make it optional? Make it only pass the "tag" parameter/argument first, and the other one when needed?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you just want to exit the function if you go into the `else`, after the `console.log()`.

Comment: You should probably return after the log. Please provide the whole code

Answer (score 1):

You may have a function with two parameters, with one of them being optional.  Here is an example:

```js
function test(p1,p2="optional"){
   console.log(p1);
   
   if(p2 == 'optional'){
        console.log("...returning\n");
        return;
   }
   else
   {
      console.log(p2);   
   }
   
}

test("param1");
test("param1","param2");
```

In this case, the first time the function is called with only param1 because param2 is optional. The second time the function is called with both parameters.